# mobile safari and uiwebview has difference in detecting phone numbers

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, datadetectortypes

Am looking at a page in mobile safari which has a text 800 LUV-1234 inside html (no tel: link). This text is automatically detected as phone number, but when i am seeing the same webpage with options like

> self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;

it is not working properly. What could be wrong ? i thought this option alone will make the same text transformed to a detectable phone number. Do you have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, the only thing I can suggest is that you ensure that self.webView is initialized and correctly points to the UIWebView instance.  Are other data detector objects correctly detected in the UIWebView?